# Update certain item in List data from RecyclerView.Adapter class

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

Is there any way to update certain List data from RecyclerView.Adapter class

here is my List class:

```
public class Idea {
    private String id, name, voted;

    public Idea(String id, String name, String voted) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.voted = voted;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getVoted() {
        return voted;
    }
}
```

my RecyclerView Adapter class:

```
public class IdeaListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<IdeaListAdapter.IdeaViewHolder> {

    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Idea> ideaList, idlst;

    public IdeaListAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Idea> ideaList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.ideaList = ideaList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public IdeaListAdapter.IdeaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.idea_list_object_layout, null);
        return new IdeaListAdapter.IdeaViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull IdeaListAdapter.IdeaViewHolder ideaViewHolder, int i) {
        final Idea idea = ideaList.get(i);

        if (idea.getVoted().equals("0")) {
            ideaViewHolder.checkBoxLikeIdeaListFragment.setChecked(false);
        } else if (idea.getVoted().equals("1")) {
            ideaViewHolder.checkBoxLikeIdeaListFragment.setChecked(true);
        }

        ideaViewHolder.checkBoxLikeIdeaListFragment.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b) {
                    *** Update my idea.getVoted() here ***
                } else {
                    *** Update my idea.getVoted() here ***
                }
            }
        });
        ideaViewHolder.textViewNameIdeaListFragment.setText(idea.getName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return ideaList.size();
    }

    class IdeaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewNameIdeaListFragment;
        CheckBox checkBoxLikeIdeaListFragment;

        public IdeaViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewNameIdeaListFragment = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNameIdeaListFragment);
            checkBoxLikeIdeaListFragment = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxLikeIdeaListFragment);
        }
    }

}
```

i would like to update my idea.getVoted() when the user click the ***checkBoxLikeIdeaListFragment***
im not quite sure how i will use the ***ideaList.set()*** at this part.

should i do it on my ***MainActivity*** ? if yes, please teach me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Setter method on your Model class `**Idea**` and access setter method to update the data.

Like this.

```
public class Idea {
    private String id, name, voted;

    public Idea(String id, String name, String voted) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.voted = voted;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getVoted() {
        return voted;
    }

    public void setVoted(String voted) {
        this.voted = voted;
    }
}
```

Use setter method of `setVoted` in your adapter class.

```
ideaViewHolder.checkBoxLikeIdeaListFragment.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
            new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            i
            ideaList.get(i).setVoted("set your data"); //here you have to upadte the vote value.
            notifiyDatasetChanged(); 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way to do this is to pass a `OnCheckedListener` on your `IdeaViewHolder` constructor and assign it to your `checkBoxLikeIdeaListFragment`.

Or on your existing code you can:

```
ideaViewHolder.checkBoxLikeIdeaListFragment.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                   ideaList.get(i).setVoted(b); // i is the int index passed to onBindViewHolder(..)
                  IdeaListAdapter.this.notifyDatasetChanged(); //update list 


            }
        });
```

Comment: ideaList.get(i) doesnt have a .setVoted function. i already tried doing ideaList.set(i, b) but it return an error:set
(int,
com.sample.Adapters.Idea)
in List cannot be applied
to
(int,
java.lang.String)

Comment: thanks @MetaSnarf i have to add setVoted on my Idea class